# Firebase onDataChange not called in a specific situation

Tags: android, firebase

I'm implementing Firebase in my Android app.

I have two methods that performs some sync operations.
Method A: query a list of things.
Method B: perform writes and reads.

Method A:

```
final Firebase ref = sFirebaseRef.child("users");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
    {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError)
    {
        ...
    }
```

When I call method A all works, but if I call method B and then method A, without close the app, the onDataChange of Method A is not called.
(Also the onCancelled method is not called)

If I call more times method B all works.

- My connection is ok(I check it before launch the method)
- I wait that all the writes are ended in method B before call method A.(I have try also with purgeOutstandingWrites() with no effect)

Why onDataChange is not called?
There are some operations that could block it?

Comment: Solved: I called goOffline in method B but the goOnline in method A was not called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I called Firebase.getApp().goOffline() in method B but the goOnline() in method A was not called.